# Google Cloud Tasks: Run a task before it's scheduled ETA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api, google-cloud-tasks

I have a use case where I schedule a task 24h into the future after an event occurs. This task represents some sort of "deadline" for other things to happen.

The scheduled task triggers a creation of a report. If not all of the above mentioned "other things" have completed by this time, then the triggered report creation process creates it anyways with the information it has at the time.

If, on the other hand, all other things **do** complete before these 24h, then ideally I'd like to re-use the same Google Cloud Task to trigger the same process (as it's identical as the previous case but will contain all of the information possible).

I would imagine the easiest way to achieve the above is to:

- schedule a task 24h into the future
- if all information arrives: run the task early before it's scheduled time

However, reading through the Google Cloud Tasks documentation I don't see the option to run the task early. However, that feature **does** exist on the Cloud Tasks console, so I was wondering if it is available in the documentation and client libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for

https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/run

NOTE: It does say however that "This command is meant to be used for manual debugging"

Comment: Thanks for that, completely missed it when reading the docs! Yeah, not sure if it would be a good idea to use it in a production environment, but yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. I'll think of other ways to solve my problem for now.